# DropDownList On telerik grid with inline Edit Option mvc

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, telerik-combobox

I am using Telerik grid for mvc project , I want drop down list to be in the grid for four values , but I want first to choose the the dropdownlist to be present at inline edit mode and to be disabled at non edit mode
 here is my bound statement

```
 column.Bound(objUser => objUser.UserState)
            .ClientTemplate(                             
                                    Html.Telerik().DropDownList()
                                    .Name("UserState<#= UserState #>")
                                    .BindTo(new SelectList(ProjectTest.Controllers.UserController.UserStateList().ToList()))
                                    .Encode(false)
                                    .ToHtmlString().Replace("{", "{{").Replace("}", "}}")).Encoded(false)

        .Title("User State");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been wrestling with this too. take a look at the link below, in which I asked the same type of question. In my case, I managed to get this working, but still have some questions about HOW I got it working. Anyway, I hope this helps ...

[Telerik MVC Grid: How to use DropDownList in a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087546/telerik-mvc-grid-how-to-use-dropdownlist-in-a-column)